# QML: How to truncate a string without cutting off characters?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am trying to truncate a string by a specified length without cutting off any words. I tried using a regular expression to do this, but it appears to not work when I try to use a variable to specify the length I want the string to be. Here is my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: background
    property string contactName: "John Doe"
    property string lastText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque."
    property int lastTextMaxLen: 40

    Image {
        id: contactPhoto
        width: 100
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        source: "qrc:/qtquickplugin/images/template_image.png"
        anchors.bottomMargin: 25
        anchors.topMargin: 25
        anchors.leftMargin: 25
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        y: 25
        height: 100
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: contactPhoto.right
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 20
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0

        Text {
            id: contactNameTxt
            width: 90
            height: 25
            text: contactName
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            font.pixelSize: 20
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 25
            font.bold: true
        }

        Text {
            id: lastTextPreview
            text: lastText.replace(new RegExp("/^(.{"+lastTextMaxLen+"}[^\s]*).*/"), "$1")
            anchors.top: contactName.bottom
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            font.pixelSize: 15
            wrapMode: Text.NoWrap
            anchors.bottomMargin: 20
            anchors.topMargin: 10


        }
    }
}
```

When I use the code above, my text appears in full, regardless of the number I set for lastTextMaxLen. Whereas, if I replace the line:

```
text: lastText.replace(new RegExp("/^(.{"+lastTextMaxLen+"}[^\s]*).*/"), "$1")
```

with:

```
text: lastText.replace(/^(.{40}[^\s]*).*/, "$1")
```

It works perfectly fine. However, I want to be able to define the truncation length in a variable so that I can have it dynamically change based on the widget size. So does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `new RegExp()` constructor is not working compared to the literal notation version is because the constructor should not include the beginning and ending slashes `"/.../"`. Removing these causes it to work as expected for me:

```
text: lastText.replace(new RegExp("^(.{"+lastTextMaxLen+"}[^\s]*).*"), "$1")
```

Secondarily, the normal QML approach for truncating strings to fit a given geometry is to use the `Text` property called [elide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop), which will add a "..." at the end of your string if it exceeds a specified width. This is very helpful for dynamically scaled UIs, and is the recommended approach. Here is a small example that shows text that will always truncate to stay inside a grey rectangle:

```
Rectangle {
    height: 50
    color: "lightgrey"
    width: parent.width  // Rectangle size fluctuates based on parent size

    Text {
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque."
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width - 10 // binds width to parent width, -10 adds 5px margin to each side after centering
        elide: Text.ElideRight // truncates text that extends past the specified width
    }
}
```

Eliding text when the box is narrow:

[image: Small size]

Eliding text when the box is much wider:

[image: Wide size]

One last thing to note is that `elide` will only work when your `Text` item has a fully-specified `width`, which can either mean explicitly setting its `width` property or giving it `anchors.right` and `anchors.left`, etc.